# how to set different image sources for different widths of the screen?

Tags: php, html, media-queries

I have a question: I need to show JPG pictures, if screen width is smaller than 1024px and GIF video, if screen size is bigger.

Trick #1: There should be downloaded only one of them.
Trick #2: Can't be css background property, cos image sorce is random content of directory on server.
Trick #3: Server language is php.

Comment: #2 seems a non-issue, you can write css - using php if necessary - in the head of your page. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this without comment?

Comment: I would imagine it was downvoted due to lack of evidence of effort on OP's part.

Comment: I make a template for wordpress with plugin control. You can't just put everything you want to header from template of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use JQuery to determine which image to load you can try this.

In your PHP set up the image like so:

```
<img data-jpg="img-url-1.jpg" data-gif="img-url-2.gif" />
```

The path of each image is defined in the tag as a data-attribute

Then allow your JQuery to run after the DOM loads and determine the screen size. Based on that value, set the `src` attribute of the `<img />` to the appropriate URL.

```
$(function(){
    if($('body').width() > 1024) { $('img').attr("src", $('img').attr("data-jpg")); } 
    else { $('img').attr("src", $('img').attr("data-gif")); }
});
```

Working Example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/utPc2/)

Comment: This looks very usefull, thanx alot, will test it in my project.

Answer (score 0):

The `picture` element will let you do just that ([WHATWG spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/edits.html#the-picture-element)).

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="examples/images/large.gif" media="(min-width: 1024px)">
    <source srcset="examples/images/default-small.jpg">
    <img src="examples/images/default-small.jpg">
</picture>
```

As of July 2014 it's only in [beta builds of browsers](http://alistapart.com/blog/post/testing-responsive-images) yet. But you can use a polyfill (i.e. some JavaScript to emulate the element in unsupported browsers): see [Picturefill](http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/)

Note that the `img` is not only a fall-back but is always needed: The `source` elements just provide alternative sources for the `img` element. For more info, see for example [this guide](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/14/responsive-images-done-right-guide-picture-srcset/).

Comment: What about browser download everything that goes in img src anyway?

Comment: If you're using Picturefill replace `<img src=` with `<img srcset=`, then the browser won't download it. Browsers with srcset-support will only download one anyhow.

Comment: At the end we have img src as a fallback, so fallback downloaded anyway... or not?